# How to initalize a struct with a fixed size array as a member element?

Tags: memory-management, struct, rust

I have the following struct

```rust
struct Sudoku {
    field: [[u32; 9]; 9]
}
```

If I initalize it like this `let su: Sudoku;` everything seems all right, but using a method of the struct gives me this error `^^ use of possibly uninitialized 'method'`. So I try to initalize the struct with the array like this `let su: Sudoku{field: [[u32; 9]; 9]};` which gives me this error

```rust
98 |     let su: Sudoku{field: [[u32; 9]; 9]};
   |                   ^ expected one of 7 possible tokens here
```

So there are two questionmarks up my mind. First, generally how do I use fixed size arrays in structs and properly initalise them. And why do I need to initalise fixed size arrays anyway, aren't they for primitives automatically nulled out in memory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When initializing a variable with a struct you must use an equals sign, just like with any other assignment.

So first of all, we should add an equals sign. There are two options for placement:

```
// A
let su: Sudoku = { field: [[u32; 9]; 9] };
// B
let su = Sudoku { field: [[u32; 9]; 9] };
```

Both will still error but for different reasons.

```
// A
error[E0425]: cannot find value `field` in this scope
 --> src/main.rs:7:24
  |
7 |     let su: Sudoku = { field: [[u32; 9]; 9] };
  |                        ^^^^^
  |                        |
  |                        not found in this scope
  |                        expecting a type here because of type ascription

error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/main.rs:7:24
  |
7 |     let su: Sudoku = { field: [[u32; 9]; 9] };
  |                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected struct `Sudoku`, found array of 9 elements
  |
  = note: expected type `Sudoku`
             found type `[[u32; 9]; 9]`

// B
error[E0423]: expected value, found builtin type `u32`
 --> src/main.rs:7:32
  |
7 |     let su = Sudoku { field: [[u32; 9]; 9] };
  |                                ^^^ not a value
```

If you know Rust syntax, you know that `{ ... }` is valid as block syntax in almost any situation. One exception is when initializing a struct, in which case the opening bracket must be immediately preceded by the type the struct.

So, **B** is more correct. Let's fix that last error, which is telling you to replace the type with a value in order to make it work.

```
let su = Sudoku { field: [[0; 9]; 9] };
```

You can use any value there, every element in the multi-dimensional array will be filled with it.

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=218aa6edf267592485ba4ae5fa9a92f1))

Comment: One aspect is missing in the answer, IMHO: Especially if you have performance critical code, you might NOT want to default init the array. Examples out of board games domain, could be a Move List, which needs to go onto the stack and then will be filled by a move generator function, further down in the search function. Or even partially filled or lazily filled. And in many games, the number of moves in a position is not constant. No one will bother about the "empty" slots in the array.